# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" Linux Mint

Tags: linux, c++11, gcc, mingw

I am trying to compile winApi on Linux (Mint) with this command

`i586-mingw32msvc-g++ Test.cpp -o Test -std=c++11`

but the error generated is

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

And here is g++ -v

```
nikola@server ~/Repo/CPA++ $ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```

All the solutions i read were to update the version of gcc/g++, but as you can see the version is 4.8.4, I am totally confused even i tried -std=c++0x but i still get the same error. Have you got a solution ?

Comment: can you execute `i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -v`? you are probably having more than 1 g++ here.

Comment: Using built-in specs.
Target: i586-mingw32msvc
Configured with: /build/buildd/mingw32-4.2.1.dfsg/build_dir/src/gcc-4.2.1-2-dfsg/configure -v --prefix=/usr --target=i586-mingw32msvc --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads --enable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-multilib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.2.1-sjlj (mingw32-2)

Comment: it's a little mess, but the version is too old :/

Comment: yeah that is your issue

Comment: do you know how i can change the version ?

Comment: getting a newer compiler I would say. either by installing one or building one yourself but that is a more complicated issue